# C# Products catalog, how to navigate through tables by ID to get end up at selected product?

Tags: c#, sql

I made a C# console warehouse app, basicly i have products, employees, categories, subcategories with CRUD and all works fine.
But i would like to add a catalog option, to navigate through first choosing what catalog the user would like to see sub-categories from, where he then can choose to see products from that sub-category, and at the end choose a specific product to see detailed view about that product.

This could have done cleaner by splitting it into methods, please see through that.
My catalog class:

```
        public static void catalogMenu()
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            SqlConnection conn = db.connection();
            conn.Open();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Categories:\n");

            string SQL1 = (@"SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories");
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(SQL1, conn);
            SqlDataReader sdr1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-15}", "ID:", "Category:\n");
            while (sdr1.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-15}", sdr1[0], sdr1[1]);
            }
            sdr1.Close();

            Console.Write("\nEnter a category id: ");
            string categoryinput = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Sub-categories:\n");

            string SQL2 = (@"SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategoryName FROM SubCategories");
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(SQL2, conn);
            SqlDataReader sdr2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-10}", "ID:", "Navn:\n");
            while (sdr2.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-10}", sdr2[0], sdr2[1]);
            }
            sdr2.Close();

            Console.Write("\nEnter a sub-category id: ");
            string subcategoryinput = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Products:\n");

            string SQL3 = (@"SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM Products");
            SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(SQL3, conn);
            using SqlDataReader sdr3 = command3.ExecuteReader();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-20}", "ID:", "Produkt:\n");
            while (sdr3.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-20}",
                        sdr3.GetInt32(0), sdr3.GetString(1));
            }
            sdr3.Close();

            Console.Write("\nEnter a product id to get Detailed view about the product!: ");
            string productinput = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Detailed product view:\n");

            string SQL = (@"SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductStock, SubCategoryName, EmployeeName, ProductCreatedDate FROM Products
                          left join SubCategories on Products.ProductSubCategoryID=SubCategories.SubCategoryID
                          left join Employees on Products.ProductEmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
                          WHERE (ProductID Like @ProductID);");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
            using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-20} {2,-10} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15}", "ID:", "Product:", "Stock:", "Sub-Category:", "Edited by:", "Last edited:\n");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-5} {1,-20} {2,-10} {3,-15} {4,-15} {5,-15}",
                        reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetString(4), reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));
            }
            reader.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: What role does BASIC play here?

Comment: Well.. i am self teaching c# student, worked with this as my first project for two weeks. im not counting this as advanced c#? or is it? in that case i am moving a lot faster than i was hoping.

Comment: What's the point of asking for Category input and SubCategory input if you just show all the Products without a WHERE condition using the inputs requested? Adding a Catalog input will change nothing how the Product is selected and shown

Comment: Also the finaly query while properly using a parameter to extract a product doesn't add any parameter to the command collection. So that last query will fail for a missing parameter

Comment: Sorry, maybe this was unclear, but this is not a working code. i am stuck, i dont know how to choose to go from 1 ID to the next table, based on what ID i choose. 

I am aware that i need to use some kind of WHERE statement based on the ID i choose. but i have no clue how to make it, i am looking for answers to move in the right direction.

Comment: @MichaelAggerholm: BASIC is a programming language and the [tag:basic] tag is for questions involving that language. It isn't meant to denote "basic" topics as in "not advanced" topics. And there seems to be no relation to BASIC in your question. Read the tag's description when adding a tag and make sure it makes sense for your question!

Comment: You are talking about Catalogs but it seems that you are referring to the Categories table instead

Comment: Isnt a catalog a way to browse through products, maybe based on what categories the products are found in?

Comment: I like using a DataAdpater to put results into a DataTable.  Then you can query the DataTable in c# to filter results.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable`, so should be in `using` blocks (if you do this, you won't need to worry about `Close`ing them, which will be done by the implicit `Dispose`).